# How to use Lora Module (E32-868T30D) between 865-867MHZ

Tags: rf, lora

In India the allowed Lora frequency is between 865-867 MHZ and the module E32-868T30D is advertised for 868 MHZ. I am not sure if we can use the board within the specified range as mandated by Indian laws. Any help on how to use this board in the allowed range or any other board will be helpful.

[Lora Board](https://www.ebyte.com/en/product-view-news.html?id=189)

Answer (score 1):

While the E32-868T30D defaults to 868 MHz, the *E32-868T30D User Manual* tells me that parameter 4 allows the user to set the communications channel:

> [image: Screenshot of datasheet, showing how to set the communication channel.]

Writing 0x03, 0x04 or 0x05 should select 865, 866 or 867 MHz respectively. Depending on precisely how the spread-spectrum algorithm works, and how wide a spectrum is used, it may only be legal to select 0x04.